# What is the effect of changing the SEED in OMNET++ VS in SUMO for Vehicular Network simulation?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I noticed that setting the `seed-set` in the "ini" file for a Veins-OMNET++ simulation, will only affect the communication-related values by comparing different runs at a specific time. i.e. at a particular time for different runs, the vehicles' mobilities values (x,y, speed, direction) are relatively the same. Could you please confirm that?
However, when I set the `<seed value="seedValue" />` in the "mapname.launchd.xml" file, the mobilities of the vehicles change between runs. My second question is, Is changing the seed for SUMO affect the traffic flow (veh/h) set in the route file (.rou.xml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seed-set` controls OMNeT++/Veins parameters defined as random variables in your `omnetpp.ini` file, something like `**.packetSize = uniform(100B, 500B)`. SUMO's seed does the same job on the SUMO side. I assume you use `VeinsInetMobility` in your scenario -- in that case your speed and positions distribution is controlled by SUMO's seed since all computations are happening there, if you use any of inet's internal mobilities and set it in `omnetpp.ini`file -- then it is controlled by `seed-set`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You confirmed what I thought. However, do you know if the seed of SUMO changes the traffic flow values that I set in the rou.xml file?

Comment: @FadySamann from the [official guide](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Randomness.html): 
"The simulation uses multiple RNG instances to decouple different simulation aspects: a) randomness when loading vehicles (typeDistribution, speed deviation,...), b) probabilistic flows, c) vehicle driving dynamics. d) vehicle devices

Comment: Yes, but in terms of the probabilistic flows, I tried two rou files with high and low traffic flows and different seeds. The simulations gave me as expected large number of vehicles for the high-traffic flow scenario and a smaller number of vehicles for the low-traffic flow scenario. So, I guess the seed of SUMO did not effect the flow set in rou file